# How do I plot a binomial probability distribution?

Tags: statistics, distribution

I have calculated a set of binomial distributions giving me the probabilities of finding **n** number of objects given a sample of **N** objects.

I calculated this using the Percent Point Function (PPF) (a.k.a. the inverse cumulative function) using the scipy.stats.distributions package.

Now that I want to plot a probability distribution a question emerges: *Which package and function in python should I use for this?* I've found a few useful resources like: http://goo.gl/Q2UjxX but I am still no closer (most likely I am missing something).

Say n = 2 and N = 10. *How would I go about creating the plot below?*:

The x-axis shows the range of values from 0 - n/N (where N > n always).
The y-axis shows the probability of n/N.

[image: Probability distribution constructed for a sample size N = 10 and n = 2.]

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Hi Paul, I think you would be better served asking your question in one of the mathematics stacks. Such as http://math.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was initially considering this place too: http://stats.stackexchange.com/